# mongodb java aggregate return empty result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i need to use mongodb java aggregate function to detect duplicated documents in collection, this is the query i ran from command line and it worked:

```js
db.placements.aggregate(
    {$group:{ "_id: "$campaign", total:{$sum:1}}}, 
    {$match: {total: {$gt:2}}}, 
    {$limit:10}, 
    {$skip:0}
);
```

and this is the java code i wrote:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$campaign");
groupFields.put("total", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));     
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

DBObject matchFields = new BasicDBObject("total", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 2));
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields);

collection.aggregate(match, group, new BasicDBObject("$skip", 0), new BasicDBObject("$limit", 10));
```

but it always return empty result. can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Yes. You reversed the order of your `group` and `match` pipeline stages. So `group` comes before `match` as per the example you gave that works. Also the `$skip` operator is not required as well as being also in the wrong order in the first example.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't realize the order matters, when ran from the command line, i can do it in any order. seems Java client is not that flexible.